# C# Файл каждый раз скачивается с разным хешем

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Скачиваю файлы с сервера по http обычным WebClient.DownloadFileAsync();
Файл не один, их много, качаю каждый по одному. Все файлы скачиваются корректно кроме одного, точнее он скачивается, но не с тем хешем который на сервере. Если скачивать файл напрямую по ссылке из браузера, то с каждым скачиванием хеш один и тот же, то есть проблемы нет. Никогда с таким ещё не сталкивался, что может быть?

```
private void DownloadInjureFile(int index = 0)
{
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

        client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (index + 1 >= PatchFileList.Count)
                return;

            DownloadInjureFile(++index);
        };

        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Path.Combine(DownloadLink, PatchFileList[index].Path.Replace(@"\", "/"))), Path.Combine(SavePath, PatchFileList[index].Path));
}
```

PatchFileList - коллекция строк содержащая директорию и полное название файла.

DownloadLink - путь к которому прибавляется директория и название файла чтобы получить прямую ссылку на скачивание.

SavePath - выбранное место на компьютере куда будут скачиваться файлы, к нему также прибавляется директория и название файла.

Comment: 1. `WebClient` устарел, не используйте его для новых разработок! 2. Тут может быть что угодно, от банального заголовка, который ждет сайт, до сжатия. Вы можете нам предоставить воспроизводящий, самодостаточный, минимальный пример?

Comment: Файл закэширован. WebClient берёт его из кэша. Задайте свойство CachePolicy.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov к сожалению это не принесло никаких результатов :(

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Предоставил код скачивания

Comment: А как вы проверяете хеш?

Comment: Не кажется странным то, что вы используете асинхронные методы в простом `void` методе и не ожидаете его? Также не пойму, для чего вам тут рекурсия?

Comment: 1. А он как-то сообщает, что файл успешно скачался? Может сервер разрывает соединение, а ты об этом и не в курсе? 2. using вроде не хватает, но его тут фиг присобачишь, может и не надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, это не те асинхронные, которые с тасками, сигнатура вызываемого метода `public void DownloadFileAsync (Uri address, string fileName);`, а о том, что скачивание закончилось, он сообщает в событии. А рекурсия для того, чтобы очередь на скачивание файлов сделать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всё скачивание - отдельный класс. Сначала вызывается функция проверки хешей файлов (для этого создаётся отдельный поток), в ходе проверки хешей файлы заносятся в коллекцию PatchFileList, затем внутри этого же потока вызывается DownloadInjuredFile, которая производит поочерёдное скачивание файлов

Comment: Сравни скачанный файл с верным - чем они отличаются?

Comment: @Qwertiy Отличаются хешем и размером, каждый раз размер гуляет на несколько десятков килобайт, но почему то запуску игры это не мешает

Comment: @waparabka, в меньшую или в большую сторону? Может там просто сервер взломали и он дописывает вирус?

Comment: Может ли быть проблема конкретно в сервере? Абсолютно все файлы кроме одного скачиваются корректно. Количество файлов, на заметку - 478

Comment: @waparabka, ссылку можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код вроде верный. Это сервер глючит - хром точно так же пишет про ошибку сети и скачивает файлы разного размера:

[image: скриншот скачивания]

[image: скриншот со скачанными файлами]

Comment: Если "глючит сервер", то это явно проблема, которая больше не воспроизводится или опечатка. Какая ценность данного вопроса для SO? Вместо ответа может стоит закрыть, не?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну вопрос содержит вроде бы рабочий код для скачивания, думаю, он какую-то ценность представляет?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хотя, есть вероятность, что ошибку скачивания можно было как-то всё же проверить не по хэшу файла - было бы неплохо увидеть такой ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, для чего тогда закрывашка "больше не воспроизводится"? Вот ок, я задаю вопрос, даю рабочий код и спрашиваю "Ребят, ну не то получаю, почему?" В ответ мне приходит "Дело не в вас, дело в сервере, он чудит и дает неверный результат". И это разве не подходит под критерии той самой закрывашки? Я думаю, еще как подходит и стоит закрывать, даже, если в вопросе рабочий код. А ценность... Ценность в чем? В том, что автор использует устаревший класс, где он лишь вызывает метод `DownloadFileAsync()`? В чем ценность то? Мне кажется любой получит сразу похожий код по запросу "как скачать файл".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну я скачивал файлы другим кодом. Лучше напиши ответ, как ошибку нормально увидеть и обработать - вот и будет польза.

Comment: А как это вообще относится к вопросу? Вопрос звучит как "Файл каждый раз скачивается с разным хешем", ответ "Вам отдает такой файл сам сервер", ок, допустим мы можем это улучшить и написать, как обработать ошибку, но это ведь не изменит тот факт, что данный код, что в вопросе, не воспроизведет проблему с валидным адресом. То есть, мы имеем вопрос, который **не воспроизводится!**. А по поводу увидеть ошибку - убрать недоасинк и будет вам [ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCsRJ.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну если при ошибке сервера код падает с исключением, то это хорошо, если молча сохраняет битый файл, то плохо. В принципе, сервер, разрывающий соединение до полной передачи файла, написать можно, а значит проблема будет воспроизводиться. А в коде на скриншоте ты используешь другой метод.

Comment: Да, я использую метод, который дожидается завершения, а не некий недоасинк, который не дожидается, пропускает код дальше и что в итоге не позволяет отловить ошибки, которые он кидает. Но это не отменят тот факт, что вопрос не про это! Давайте мы сейчас с вами улучшим код автора до идеала, распишем каждую строку что и как делает и так далее, будет это относиться к вопросу? Нет конечно, ибо вопрос "скачанный с сервера файл битый" и ответа на него кроме как "вам такой файл отдает сам сервер" быть не может! Если бы он звучал как "Почему я не получаю ошибку?", тогда уже да, ваши аргументы уместны.

Comment: Вот давайте предположим, что я сейчас разрабатываю программу, некий клиент, который качает файлы и вот незадача, мой код постоянно качает "битый" файл, у которого разный хэш, разный размер. Я в недоумении иду в мой любимый поисковик и пишу `c# файл скачивается с разным хешем`, нахожу это "недоразумение", вижу ваш ответ, который гласит "А у вас проблема с сервером", ну и что, мне это даст пользы хоть какой-либо? Я вижу древний код, который сама Microsoft советует не использовать, вижу кучу бесполезных для меня комментариев и этот ответ. Вот мне хоть немного это поможет в решении проблемы?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну автору помогло, значит да :)

Comment: Вы это сейчас серьезно? Я вас как модератора прошу следить за порядком на SO, закрывать то, что должно быть закрыто, а вы вместо того, чтоб закрыть вопрос, всячески оправдываете свой ответ, которого быть не должно! Я вам привел уйму доводов тому, что этот вопрос бесполезен и не воспроизводится, но нет, нам же важно чтоб только автору была польза, верно? Извините, но вы сейчас упали в моих глазах как модератор и дальше я не вижу смысла вести этот диалог.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а я с ними не согласен. Если ты хочешь закрыть вопрос - проголосуй за его закрытие и дождись, пока ещё 4 человека с тобой согласятся, а не убеждай одного модератора в комметариях.

Comment: Так я проголосовал с самого начала и уже как видите 4 голоса от сообщества за закрытие, надеялся на ваш профессионализм, но им тут и не пахнет, увы.